# Populate a spinner based on the selection of another spinner

Tags: android, spinner, actionlistener

I have to populate states depending on the selected country. I also have to capture the items selected in other `spinners`. But the listener methods are not getting called.

```
countriesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
statesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
yearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.countriesSpinner:
        {
            Log.i("selected country",selectedCountry);
            selectedCountry = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            populateStates();
            ArrayAdapter stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
            statesSpinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
        }
        break;

        case R.id.statesSpinner:
        {
            selectedState=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }
        break;

        case R.id.yearSpinner:
        {
            selectedYear = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }
    }



}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you got the Switch Id wrong...your need to use `parent.getId()`

try this:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()) 
    {         
        case R.id.countriesSpinner:

            Log.i("selected country",selectedCountry);
            selectedCountry = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            populateStates();
            ArrayAdapter stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
            statesSpinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
            break;              

        case R.id.statesSpinner:
            selectedState=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            break;              
         case R.id.yearSpinner:
            selectedYear=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            break;
    }
}
```